# Bluetooth dongle not being detected in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: usb, bluetooth, 20.10

I recently bought a Bluetooth dongle to connect my headphones to my pc, on Windows is working fine, it discovers all devices around, but as Ubuntu is my primary system, i wanted it to work on it.

here's the output for hciconfig:

```
~$ hciconfig

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10  ACL MTU: 310:4  SCO MTU: 64:8
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:1244 acl:0 sco:0 events:74 errors:0
    TX bytes:2776 acl:0 sco:0 commands:78 errors:4
```

if you want the output for some command just ask it :)

Comment: Run `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`.

Comment: It says "Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)"